# Facebook likebox script for websites

Tags: javascript, facebook, web, facebook-likebox

I have used the script provided for the likebox to create a user macro for my clients Confluence system.

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#x fbml=1"></script>`

<fb:like-box
  href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Canada-YMCA-Federal-Government-Youth-Internships/215740255103118"
  show_faces="true" stream="true"
  header="true">
</fb:like-box>
```

My client is planning on upgrading to Confluence 4.0. Connfluence 4.0 has made a lot of changes with their macros and uses xhtml instead of wiki markup. I have upgraded my own version of Confluence to 4.0 and I am getting the following error on the page that I inserted the facebook-likebox macro on:

> Error rendering macro 'facebook-likebox' : Failed to transform the HTML macro template for display.
>
> Nested message: The XML content could not be parsed. There is a problem at line 11, column 161.
>
> Parser message: Undeclared namespace prefix "fb" at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [11,161]

It is a problem with the script [here](http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#x) and the html character entities.

When I navigate to http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#x I see the JavaScript. Is this the full script for the likebox? If I have the the full script I may be able to make the necessary changes.

Could I get some feedback on this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Confluence, so not sure how to change this in your setup (maybe someone else will know) but you need to tell Confluence about the `fb` and `og` prefixes Facebook uses for the XFBML elements in the Social Plugins and some of the Open Graph meta tags

In a standard HTML page this is done with

```
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
              xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
              xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

if you can't get this to play nicely with your configuration, most of the Facebook social plugins also have a HTML5 or iframe version which won't require use of 'fb' tags (like the `<fb:like-box>`' tag which the Javascript SDK replaces with the Like Box iframe)